# CI - Using the right package.json while in other branch

Tags: node.js, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

i've a repo with `master` and `branch1`. I'm writing test in `branch1` with mocha / chai and i've changed the package json (forked a repo and maded some changes to it), but Travis seems to build still the old one, even if i changed my package.json. I've just forked and replaced the version in the package.json with the name of the repo (like everytime).

Anyone have experienced something similar? I'm missing the right way to make Travis build the package.json that is in the Pull Request where i'm working?

Answer (score 1):

just trying to clarify some things in your question :)

Are you submitting a pull request to the upstream repo that you forked from, and wanting the upstream repo's Travis integration to build your code?

If so, it may be that the upstream repo's maintainer doesn't have the "Build PR" setting turned on in Travis for their repo. You could ask them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882306/how-to-configure-travis-ci-to-build-pull-requests-merges-to-master-w-o-redunda) for more details. Or maybe your PR can't be merged, as described in the [Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/).

Or are you working on a branch within your own repo, which you forked from upstream?

If so, you need to set up Travis integration yourself on your own forked repo.

Comment: yes, i forked the upstream repo, modified the package.json in the PR that i made and now trying to make Travis build my PR for checking that everything is good. I was not aware of the "Build PR" option, i did not installed Travis, thanks for you info, i'll let you know as soon as possible

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could show us your repo, if it's public?

Comment: I would like to do it, but unluckly is not public. The PR build are already turned on and the most crazy thing is the in my local repo, when i do an npm install and then run test with mocha i don't get any error, while the remote PR still get the error that i used to have when using the wrong package

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem specifing in the package.json the commit id of the node module. Probabily not the best way to accomplish this, but the test passed now.